# Change window transparency and prevent mouse clicks for this window

Tags: window-manager, window

I want to change the transparency of a window and I want to prevent clicks on this window, like transparency popups. Is there any plugin for this?

Let me explain question with pictures. I can click to back window of this:

[image]

And I want to click to back window in this:

[image]

Comment: I hope I have interpreted the question correctly. If not, then you can undo my changes [here](https://askubuntu.com/posts/632956/revisions).

Comment: @A.B. oh my. You are good at reading between the missing word. I did understand half of it. Guessing game...